# Why is there a narrowing conversion warning from int to short when adding shorts? (C++)

Tags: c++, types, type-conversion, narrowing

I have a code similar to this for the following array:

```
long int N = 424242424242; //random number
short int* spins = new short int spins[N];
std::fill(spins, spins+N, 1);
```

Now let's suppose for some reason I want to add a couple of elements of that array into a short int called nn_sum:

```
short int nn_sum = spins[0] + spins[1];
```

However, when I do this on CLion IDE, Clang-Tidy marks it yellow and tells me:

```
Clang-Tidy: Narrowing conversion from 'int' to signed type 'short' is implementation-defined
```

Why is this happening? Why is there any narrowing at all? Does C++ convert the shorts to ints when adding them? If so why, and is there something I can do to make it work better? Maybe even ditch the shorts entirely?

Keep in mind that I have code like this in a *very* computationally intensive part of the application so I want to make it as efficient as possible. Any other suggestion would also be appreciated.

Comment: integer promotion. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion

Comment: *Does C++ convert the shorts to ints when adding them?* - Exactly. All arithmetic operations are performed at least on `int` type. I suppose `static_cast<short>(spins[0] + spins[1])` should silence this warning. As to whether ditch `short` or not - depeneds on your program. If making array twice as big will not matter, then use `int` and you will not have to worry. If memory is scarce, `short` may be needed.

Comment: Hmmm alright... The thing I'm worried is that I want the spins array to be really really big (hence the long int designation for N...). Will that cast take something away from performance? Or is it better if I just make nn_sum an int instead? That may also be a solution now that I think about it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because of integer promotion. The result of adding two `short` values is not `short`, but `int`.

You can check this with cppinsights.io:

```
short a = 1;
short b = 2;
auto c = a + b;  // c is int
```

Demo: https://cppinsights.io/s/68e27bd7

Comment: Alright, so what would you propose the best way to address this is?

Comment: Basically, you have two options: use `int` rather than `short` for your array (I don't suppose it will make much of a difference unless you have millions of elements) or cast the result back to `short` after performing the addition.

Comment: I actually do have millions of elements... That's why I had an issue...